# Making the matrix $A_{mn} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}x_m k_n}$ unitary

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, fourier-transform, unitary-matrices

Let's say we have a matrix

$$A_{mn} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N} x_m k_n}$$

where $0 \leq x_m < N$, and each of $m, n$ is an integer from $0$ to $N - 1$. If $x_m$ is an integer where $x_m = m$, we can find that $k_n = n$ makes the matrix $A_{mn}$ unitary, i.e., $\mathbf{AA}^H = \mathbf{A}^H\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{I}$.
However, if $x_m$ is not integer (but assuming the values of $x_m$ are all unique), does there exist a set of $k_n$ that could make the matrix $A_{mn}$ unitary? If it exists, how to find $k_n$?

Comment: We have (for $N \geq 2$): $$(AA^H)_{m,m} = \sum_{s=0}^{N - 1} e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}x_mk_s} \overline{e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}x_mk_s}}= \sum_{s=0}^{N-1} \left|e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}x_mk_s}\right|^2 = N \neq 1$$ so $A$ itself can't ever be unitary. (An easy fix to re-give sense to the question would be to multiply $A$ by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$)

Comment: @BrunoB, thanks for the correction. I forgot to put the normalization factor there.

Comment: @Firman I suspect that the answer is yes in the specific case that the $x_m$ are in some kind of arithmetic projection (i.e. $x_m = a + bm$ for some $a,b \in \Bbb R$ with $b$ non-zero), but no more generally. Would a proof of that first statement be useful to you?

Comment: @BenGrossmann, yes, the proof of your first statement would be useful, although it does not completely solve the problem. When you said "no more generally", did you mean it's impossible to get the matrix unitary for all cases of $x_m$ (with uniqueness and the boundary requirements)?

Comment: @Firman I don't know what you mean by uniqueness and boundary requirements, but I believe that there are some $x_j$ for which no suitable $k_j$ exist

Comment: @BenGrossmann what I meant by uniqueness is that there is no 2 $x_m$ with the same values (every $x_m$ is distinct), and by boundary requirement I meant $0 \leq x_m < N$

Comment: @Firman I see. Yes that's what I meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suitable set of $k_n$ does not necessarily exist; here's a counterexample for $N=3$. Take
$$
x_0 = 0, \quad x_1 = \frac 13, \quad x_2 = 1.
$$
The orthogonality of the first two columns gives us
$$
0 = \sum_{n=0}^2 e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{3} k_n(x_1 - x_0)} 
=  \sum_{n=0}^2 e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{3} \frac 13 k_n} = \sum_{n=0}^2 e^{-i\frac{2\pi}9 k_n}
$$
Adding in the result from the other two pairs gives us
$$
0 = \sum_{n=0}^2 e^{-i\frac{2\pi}9 k_n}= 
\sum_{n=0}^2 e^{-i\frac{4\pi}9 k_n}=
\sum_{n=0}^2 e^{-i\frac{6\pi}9 k_n}.
$$
Take $z_n = e^{-i\frac{2\pi}9 k_n}$; note that $|z_n| = 1$. The above equations can be rewritten as
$$
0 = z_0 + z_1 + z_2 = z_0^2 + z_1^2 + z_2 ^2 = z_0^3 + z_1^3 + z_2^3.
$$
With [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), we can deduce that the unique solution to this system of equations is $z_0 = z_1 = z_2  = 0$. Our $z_n$ are non-zero, so there are no suitable $k_n$.

Comment: The counterexample here violates the boundary requirement: $0 \leq x_m < N$ where $x_2 > N$.

Comment: @Firman My mistake. Still, replace $x_1$ with any sufficiently small value and $x_2$ with $3x_1$, and the same logic applies

Comment: @Firman See my latest edit

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer, but for the specific case $N = 2$ there do exist such couples $(k_0,k_1)$ for every $(x_0,x_1)$ with $x_0 \neq x_1$, and we can have them all:

In that case, since we already have $1$s on the diagonal and $AA^H$ is hermitian, it suffices to check that $(AA^H)_{0,1} = 0$ :
$$(AA^H)_{0,1} = \sum_{s=0}^{2-1} e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{2}x_0k_s} \overline{e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{2}x_1k_s}} = e^{i\pi(x_1 - x_0)k_0} + e^{i\pi(x_1 - x_0)k_1}$$
As such:
$$\begin{split}(AA^H)_{0,1} = 0 & \Leftrightarrow e^{i\pi(x_1 - x_0)k_0} + e^{i\pi(x_1 - x_0)k_1} = e^{i\pi(x_1-x_0)k_0}\left(1+e^{i\pi(x_1-x_0)(k_1-k_0)}\right) = 0\\
& \Leftrightarrow 1+e^{i\pi(x_1 - x_0)(k_1 - k_0)} = 0\\
& \Leftrightarrow \pi(x_1 - x_0)(k_1 - k_0) \equiv \pi \mod 2\pi\\
& \Leftrightarrow k_1 - k_0 \equiv \frac{1}{x_1 - x_0} \mod \frac{2}{x_1 - x_0}\end{split}$$

And that last condition can be satisfied for any choice of $k_0$, which gives us the existence of the couples $(k_0,k_1)$ as well as their full description.

However, like Ben Grossmann in the comments above is saying, it might get trickier, at least for $N \geq 4$:
you'll need the $N$ unknown variables $k_0,\dots,k_{N-1}$ to satisfy $\frac{N(N-1)}{2} > N$ (non-linear) equations, and so intuitively, by overdetermination of the system, there might not always exist solutions, though of course this remains to be proven.
($N = 3$ might still be feasible? but it's three equations with three unknowns and it's probably not going to be as easy as $N = 2$.)